# ngRepeat is not working in colorbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am trying to repeat some number in array and want output in colorbox, but for some reason i can't see the the numbers from array. Am i not escaping any special character or missing concatenation ? Thanks

```
$scope.someNumber = [1,2,3,4];
jQuery.colorbox({html:"<div ng-model= 'someNumber' ng-repeat='number in someNumber'>{{number}}</div>"});
```

Comment: if you need to use attach html which has angular directives then you have to use `$compile` service in order to bind the scope variables and the directives to the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$compile` to controller and then do it like:

```
jQuery.colorbox({html:$compile("<div ng-model= 'someNumber' ng-repeat='number in someNumber'>{{number}}</div>")($scope)});
```

The reason is that the html has to be compile in order for angularjs to retrieve/evaluate expressions and make it work properly, otherwise angular can't know what happened